# Android - How I can have multiple ListView just with one adapter and Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

For example I have a `ListView` that per item have `Subcategories` and per `Subcategories` has another `Subcategories` as a result I have multiple `ListView` base Subcategories , now I need to have just `one Adapter` and just `one Activity` for all of these `ListView`.(I don't need to use `Fragment`)

I need to a sample or a link . Thanks .

Notice : I have a lot of Subcategories.

Comment: I think you want expandablelistview.

Comment: No. I have a lot Subcategories .

Comment: I think you should want this type of library. https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview